# Specifying colClasses in the read.csv

Tags: r, csv, read.csv

I am trying to specify the `colClasses` options in the `read.csv` function in R. In my data, the first column `time` is basically a character vector, while the rest of the columns are numeric.

```
data <- read.csv("test.csv", comment.char="" , 
                 colClasses=c(time="character", "numeric"), 
                 strip.white=FALSE)
```

In the above command, I want R to read in the `time` column as "character" and the rest as numeric. Although the `data` variable did have the correct result after the command completed, R returned the following warnings. I am wondering how I can fix these warnings?

> Warning messages:
> 1: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : not all columns named in 'colClasses' exist
> 2: In tmp[i[i > 0L]] <- colClasses :
> number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Derek

Answer (score 89, accepted):

The colClasses vector must have length equal to the number of imported columns. Supposing the *rest* of your dataset columns are 5:

```
colClasses=c("character",rep("numeric",5))
```

Comment: one can probably use the following to read the first line of the csv and determine how many columns there are.

scan(csv,sep=',', what="character" , nlines=1 )

Comment: This actually is an incorrect answer and threw me off for a little while. The correct answer is below. Not trying to be a jerk, just wanted to make sure it doesn't happen to anyone else.

Comment: @Rob In my case, this is still the correct answer, when you also need to specify the classes of the other variables, and they are not automatically recognized as such by `read.table`.

Answer (score 203):

You can specify the colClasse for only one columns.

So in your example you should use:

```
data <- read.csv('test.csv', colClasses=c("time"="character"))
```

Comment: Not that it matters much, but I found this to work without quoting the column name.

Comment: This approach is actually very useful when trying to read quoted integers as character. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

Assuming your 'time' column has at least one observation with a non-numeric character and all your other columns only have numbers, then 'read.csv's default will be to read in 'time' as a 'factor' and all the rest of the columns as 'numeric'. Therefore setting 'stringsAsFactors=F' will have the same result as setting the 'colClasses' manually i.e.,

```
data <- read.csv('test.csv', stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Answer (score 12):

If you want to refer to names from the header rather than column numbers, you can use something like this:

```
fname <- "test.csv"
headset <- read.csv(fname, header = TRUE, nrows = 10)
classes <- sapply(headset, class)
classes[names(classes) %in% c("time")] <- "character"
dataset <- read.csv(fname, header = TRUE, colClasses = classes)
```

Answer (score 10):

I know OP asked about the `utils::read.csv` function, but let me provide an answer for these that come here searching how to do it using `readr::read_csv` from the tidyverse.

```
read_csv ("test.csv", col_names=FALSE, col_types = cols (.default = "c", time = "i"))
```

This should set the default type for all columns as *character*, while *time* would be parsed as integer.

Answer (score 5):

For multiple datetime columns with no header, and a lot of columns, say my datetime fields are in columns 36 and 38, and I want them read in as character fields:

```
data<-read.csv("test.csv", head=FALSE,   colClasses=c("V36"="character","V38"="character"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If we combine what @Hendy and @Oddysseus Ithaca contributed, we get cleaner and a more general (i.e., adaptable?) chunk of code.

```
    data <- read.csv("test.csv", head = F, colClasses = c(V36 = "character", V38 = "character"))
```