# R converts the hash id into some strange numbers

Tags: r

I am trying to read an electronic health record in R, which is in `.csv` format. R converts the hash key `"0x58EC47CAFF4373A4573B198E080CB7552BA8EA25"` (which is an anonymised personal id) into something like this `"9.265679e+47"`. Can somebody help me understand why this is happening please?

Answer (score 2):

The 0x at the beginning of the string tells R that it's reading a hexadecimal number, which it then represents in its decimal representation. Use the colClasses argument to read that column in as character. Perhaps the answers here will help. [Specifying colClasses in the read.csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805357/specifying-colclasses-in-the-read-csv)