# Defining variable type before/while importing data

Tags: r, read.table

I am importing several tab separated files into R. In one of the columns, there are numeric IDs which are 18+ digits long. When I use read.table for this, it automatically reads that column as numeric, converts the ID into scientific format (e.g. x.xxE10) and then when I use as.character on this, it results in the same string even if the original IDs were two different numbers.

Is there any way by which I can define in R how to read the data before reading the data? Or in general, how do I solve this problem?

I am simply using the read.table command

```
df <- read.table(file="data/myfile.txt",sep="\t",header=T, stringsAsFactors=F, encoding="UTF-8")
```

Comment: Check out the `colClasses` argument to `read.table`.  [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805357/specifying-colclasses-in-the-read-csv) is one example of a relevant stackoverflow question.

Comment: works perfect. thanks! i was searching but did not come across the keyword "colClasses". thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution. my file contains 20 columns

```
df <- read.table(file="data/myfile.txt",sep="\t",header=T, stringsAsFactors=F, encoding="UTF-8", colClasses=c(rep("character",20)))
```