# Reading the .csv file as read.transactions for applying ariori() in R?

Tags: r, transactions, type-conversion, categorical-data, apriori

I have .csv data with column and 5000 rows like as follows:

```
age sex children distance  
  1   0        1        1    
  1   1        1        2   
  2   1        0        1    
  1   0        1        3    
  3   1        0        2   
  1   1        1        1
```

I want to apply association rule mining using `apriori()`. 
So tried to read the dataset using `read.transactions` as follows:

```
mar = read.transactions("Marketing campaign.csv", format = "basket", 
                        sep = ",", cols = c("age", "sex", "children", "distance"))
```

But I get the following error:

> Error in read.transactions("Marketing campaign.csv", format = "basket",  : 'cols' must be a numeric scalar for 'basket'.

Please help. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Try using `as.factor` instad of `as.character`

Comment: You can specify the class for each column using the `colClasses` argument in `read.csv` as follows: `dat <- read.csv("filename.csv", colClasses = rep("character", 4))`

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2805414/4300478

Answer (score 1):

In R, the data type  that holds categrorial variables is called `factor`. Factor vectors can easily be created with the methods `as.factor` and `factor`

```
myDf <- data.frame(
  age = c(1,1,2,1,3,1),
  sex = c(1,1,1,0,1,1),
  children = c(1,1,0,1,0,1),
  distance = c(0,2,1,3,2,1)
)

myDf
#   age sex children distance
# 1   1   1        1        0
# 2   1   1        1        2
# 3   2   1        0        1
# 4   1   0        1        3
# 5   3   1        0        2
# 6   1   1        1        1

myDf$sex <- factor(myDf$sex, labels = c("F", "M"))

myDf
#   age sex children distance
# 1   1   M        1        0
# 2   1   M        1        2
# 3   2   M        0        1
# 4   1   F        1        3
# 5   3   M        0        2
# 6   1   M        1        1
```

Comment: But I have 5000 rows of this combination. And after that, I need to apply apriori() on that. Even after converting in factors, it showing that no method or default for coercing “tbl_df” to “transactions”

Comment: I don't understand how the number of rows makes a difference here. About `transactions`: This is a completely different question than the one you asked previously. In the `arules` pasckage, there is a specific class called `transactions`. If you want help with that, mention this in the question

Comment: Is it possible that `as.transactions` works on data frames, but not `tbl_df`s?