# R barplot not displaying values correctly

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-science

Im trying to get a simple plot of a data set with countries and their total amount of covid cases, however my plot is not giving the largest numerical value of cases the largest bar.

```
Data = read.csv("covid_worldwide.csv")
Data = Data[c("Country", "Total.Cases", "Total.Deaths", "Total.Recovered","Active.Cases", "Total.Test",    "Population")]    
df_subset = Data[1:5, ]

Plot = ggplot(df_subset, aes(x = Country, y = Total.Cases)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "steelblue") +
  labs(title = "Total Cases by Country", x = "Country", y = "Total Cases")
```

For example the us has over one hundred million cases but has the smallest bar in the plot when it should be the largest.

[image: The plot in question]

any help appreciated

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and add the output from `dput(head(Data,20))`?

Comment: Your `Total.Cases` is getting read in as text ("character"), presumably because the CSV has some values that look like text. Either convert to numeric (e.g. with `readr::parse_number`) or better yet, specify the right type at import: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8185739/6851825